# Error running TopologicalBreachBurn in Whitebox GAT

Tags: dem, hydrology, flow-accumulation, whitebox-gat

I am trying to execute the TopologicalBreachBurn script in Whitebox GAT. This is my first time using this software so am generally unfamiliar with how it operates. I imported a DEM as an ASCII .txt to convert it to the required .dep format needed for the script. Then I selected a streams vector .shp. When I hit run, it gives me the error: "an error occurred during operations. See log for details."

When I open the log there is nothing there, so I am not able to ascertain what the error actually is. Anyone run into this issue or know what may be happening?

Comment: One possibility is your streams shapefile contains multipart object(s). In my test case (which reproduced error) the log says `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 80` in the `Error in Topological Breach-Burn (Stream Burning)` section. If it is the case please convert your shapefile to single parts and try to run the tool again.

Comment: @Kazuhito Thank you for this suggestion, I converted my file to singlepart features and am still receiving the error. Perhaps anyone else has a solution?

Comment: Are they the same coordinate system?

Comment: @WhiteBoxDev Might have an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and was able to get the tool to run, though I'm not exactly sure why my steps worked. In my case I did have error messages in the log.

The first error message was "`java.lang.NullPointerException`"  which wasn't much help.  But after reading the paper referenced in the help I realized that the way it worked might mean that the stream network needed to be split at all intersections, which mine was not.  I used GRASS' v.clean to break the lines at intersections and exported a shapefile.

This time I got the error message "`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Negative array index [-32769] too large for array size 952`"  I guessed that something was not right with my shapefile(since it had 952 features) so I used QGIS to convert it to a geojson file and then back into a shapefile.

Third time was a charm and it ran successfully.  I'd try using a tool like v.clean to correct topology errors and/or try converting out of the shapefile format and back in to see if either of those steps help.